# how to separate view and controller in python tkinter?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, python-3.x, lambda, tkinter

I have a problem with tkinter regarding separating UI and UI functionality in two modules,here is my code:

1-view.py

```
from tkinter import *

class View():
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.button=Button(parent,text='click me').pack()
```

2.controller.py

```
from tkinter import *
from view import *

class Controller:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.view1=View(parent)
        self.view1.button.config(command=self.callback)

    def callback(self):
        print('Hello World!')


root=Tk()
app=Controller(root)
root.mainloop()
```

on running controller.py I get the following error:

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'**

any suggestion?

also I tried to use lambda for using a callback function in another module but it didn't work.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view.py you are calling:

`self.button=Button(parent,text='click me').pack()`

The pack function doesn't return the Button object that you want to assign to self.button, which causes the AttributeError later on. You should do:

```
self.button = Button(parent, text='click me')
self.button.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

the lambda approach problem was exactly as above which is now resolved by using the pack in a new line. it seems more beautiful, here is the sample using lambda which is working fine:

1.view.py

```
from tkinter import *
from controller import *

class View():
    def __init__(self,parent):
        button=Button(parent,text='click me')
        button.config(command=lambda : callback(button))
        button.pack()


root=Tk()
app=View(root)
root.mainloop()
```

2.controller.py

```
def callback(button):
    button.config(text='you clicked me!')
    print('Hello World!')
```

using this approach we can move all functionality away from UI and make it clean and readable.